# How to select rows from pandas DataFrame array columns with certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame with array column:

```
id,classes,text
71,`["performer_146", "performer_42"]`,`adipiscing urna. molestie `
72,["performer_42"],`a ligula odio elementum, neque suscipit. egestas Maecenas`
73,["performer_146"],`vestibulum orci nec vestibulum, ligula orci et mauris lobortis, et Aliquam`
74,["performer_0"],tincidunt non interdum nunc ultrices mi accumsan elementum arcu venenatis
75,`["performer_146", "performer_42"]`, orci elementum non finibus dolor. Cras
76,`["performer_42", "performer_146"]`,`mi lectus Maecenas eleifend neque amet, `
77,["performer_146"],` platea placerat. odio Morbi rutrum, eu Cras`
```

I read this CSV and convert "classes" column's values into arrays:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar='`')
df['classes'] = df['classes'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Now I want to select rows with "performer_0" in "classes" values. Like this:

```py
df['performer_0' in df['classes']]
```

But this code doesn't work:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "d:\pyenv\pandas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line
>   2657, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: False
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "d:\pyenv\pandas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in
>   **getitem**
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "d:\pyenv\pandas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line
>   2659, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: False

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way I found is to combine `apply` and selecting:

```py
df[df['classes'].apply(lambda x: 'performer_0' in x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work on pandas 0.25+, you can make use of `explode`:

```
df[df['classes'].explode().eq(performer_0).any(level=0)]
```